# Confused between 'Near something' and 'Near to something'

Tags: prepositions

I get confused when I read 'near' and 'near to' something. I often hear people saying 'near' without 'to', but then 'near to' is also correct. For example read the following sentences:

- Where is your book?-Near my bed.
- Where is Wall Mart?-Near to my house.

Now, can I write them like this:

- Where is your book? -Near to my bed.
- Where is Wall Mart?-Near my house.

Help me in solving this. Thank You.

Comment: [This post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192319/near-near-to-and-nearby-whats-the-difference) from EL&U might help. It also talks about *nearby.* Also, some native speakers greatly prefer to use 'close to' instead of 'near to'.

Comment: Please also see [The Oxford Learners dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/near_3#near_3__15).

Answer (score 1):

I believe both are grammatical, but as a native American English speaker, *near* is much more common than *near to*. [This Oxford dictionary article](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/near-and-near-to) agrees.
I would say that usage of *to* is more likely in cases like this example from the OED article:

> She reached out her hand and drew him near to her.

where the two people/things became closer, rather than were already close together, like in the following:

> He was sitting near her.

As CarSmack mentioned, *close to* sounds more natural than *near to*. Looking at a [Google nGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=near%2C%20near%20to%2C%20close%2C%20close%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnear%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnear%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclose%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclose%20to%3B%2Cc0) of usage, we see that *near* and *close* are used at similar rates, with *close to* at less than half of both, and *near to* used a very small fraction of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, near something would work and I would use it over near to something.

Where is your book? -Near my bed.
Where is Wall Mart?-Near my house.